# C - working with Text Files

Tags: c, io, fgets, argv

Basically, I'm working on a small program in C (again, not a homework task, just some experimentation while I'm away from Uni :) ). My goal is to take a file containing lots of words all seperated by spaces, loop through the file, and whenever a space is found, replace that for a \n thus creating a large list of words.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
/*
 * 
*/
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

char myFile[100];
int i;
FILE *file;
while(argc--) {
    printf("%s\n", *argv++);
}

return 0;
}
```

Very basic what I have so far, what I need to do next is to take the arguement and whack it in the myFile array, so that I can use that as the fopen, or maybe there is another way to do this?

Beyond that, my idea was to then read a line, into an array via fgets, loop through it char by char, searching for ' ', if I find it, replace is for \n, then rewrite that line to the file. Does this sound sensible, doable?

Regards,

and Thanks!

Comment: You can (try to) open the file directly from `argv`: `file = fopen(argv[1], "r"); if (file) /* ok! don't forget to fclose(file); */;`

Comment: Why the 'read a line' step?  Can't you just read the file one character at a time and replace `' '` with `'\n'` as you go through?

Comment: I wasnt aware there was a function to read character by character from a file?

Comment: Read about `getchar`. Then when you have a few minutes find a description of the standard library (the appendix of K&R for instance) and read what is available: the c standard library is so small and simple that there is no excuse for not knowing what's in there.

Comment: I knew about getchar, I just didnt think it would work in this instance, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simplest way is to open the file in binary mode

```
FILE *fpIn = fopen( argv[1], "rb" );
```

then open a new file for writing

```
FILE* fpOut =  fopen( "tmp.out", "wb" );
```

and read byte by byte from  fpIn using [fgetc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgetc/) and write using [fputc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fputc/) to the new file

before writing check if the byte is a space (use `isspace()`), write a '\n' instead.

then delete original and rename `tmp.out` to `argv[1]`

Comment: np, you may also want to check for multiple spaces and just replace them with one newline - not sure of how your file looks like.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much exactly what K&R Exercise 1-12 asks you to do (you could redirect the input file to standard input alternately, if you want to skip the file pointers).  It's a good exercise.

FYI, a good resource for K&R solutions:
http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K&R2_solutions